# How to clone remote repo when using SSH alias

Tags: ssh, mercurial

I know my ssh configuration works because I can just type `ssh myAlias.ssh` and connect just fine.

I'm trying to use the command `hg clone ssh://myAlias.ssh//path/to/repo` and getting a `remote: ssh: Could not resolve hostname myAlias.ssh: No such file or directory`

Is it possible to use an SSH alias here?

Comment: How did you create the alias?  Hosts file?  Are you on Windows or Linux?  Have you tried using a lowercase alias like `myalias.ssh`, maybe the case is the problem.

Comment: I'm using the correct case... the alias was created in `~/.ssh/`

Comment: Ummm, maybe Mercurial does not imports ssh aliases created on `~/.ssh/config`.  As an alternative option, you can try to create the alias on the `/etc/hosts` file.  Just add a line: `1.2.3.4 youralias`, where `1.2.3.4` is the IP of your server.

Comment: Have you tried an alias name that does not have a dot? Perhaps that is causing it to try and resolve the alias.

Comment: @natchiketa The dot does not present a problem for Mercurial. I thought it might present a problem for SSH, so I tested this myself both with straight SSH and via Mercurial (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17492909/2022326)), and it worked just fine. Further evidence against the dot being a problem is that `ssh myAlias.ssh` seems to work. Now, if Mercurial is calling another SSH program due to some config option, then it could be the case that that program doesn't support dots in the aliases. Of course, at that point, the question is whether the second SSH even uses the same config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Theory

### General principles

Mercurial does work with aliases created in `~/.ssh/config` -- I use this feature all the time on Linux and OS X. This works because Mercurial doesn't try to resolve the hostname itself, but rather depends on SSH to do this (and passes the error up, when it encounters one). This is why the error is has the `ssh:` as part of its prefix. Bitbucket even has [help](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168#ConfiguremultipleSSHidentitiesforGitBash%2CMacOSX%2C%26Linux-CreateaSSHconfigfile) on setting up aliases via `.ssh/config`. (In the linked example, they use it to manage two separate identities.)  If you created an alias via another mechanism, say BASH `alias`, then this will not work because it is dependent on BASH, which Mercurial does not use.

### From the Mercurial source code

I have also gone through the Mercurial source code for `clone`, including examining `sshpeer.py` and `util.py` for the SSH related parts, and Mercurial does indeed pass along the hostname/alias to SSH for correct parsing / interpretation.

The docstring for  `class url` in `util.py` of the Mercurial (2.6.3) source code:

```
Reliable URL parser.

This parses URLs and provides attributes for the following
components:

<scheme>://<user>:<passwd>@<host>:<port>/<path>?<query>#<fragment>

Missing components are set to None. The only exception is
fragment, which is set to '' if present but empty.

If parsefragment is False, fragment is included in query. If
parsequery is False, query is included in path. If both are
False, both fragment and query are included in path.

See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt for more information.

Note that for backward compatibility reasons, bundle URLs do not
take host names. That means 'bundle://../' has a path of '../'.

Examples:

>>> url('http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt')
<url scheme: 'http', host: 'www.ietf.org', path: 'rfc/rfc2396.txt'>
>>> url('ssh://[::1]:2200//home/joe/repo')
<url scheme: 'ssh', host: '[::1]', port: '2200', path: '/home/joe/repo'>
>>> url('file:///home/joe/repo')
<url scheme: 'file', path: '/home/joe/repo'>
>>> url('file:///c:/temp/foo/')
<url scheme: 'file', path: 'c:/temp/foo/'>
>>> url('bundle:foo')
<url scheme: 'bundle', path: 'foo'>
>>> url('bundle://../foo')
<url scheme: 'bundle', path: '../foo'>
>>> url(r'c:\foo\bar')
<url path: 'c:\\foo\\bar'>
>>> url(r'\\blah\blah\blah')
<url path: '\\\\blah\\blah\\blah'>
>>> url(r'\\blah\blah\blah#baz')
<url path: '\\\\blah\\blah\\blah', fragment: 'baz'>

Authentication credentials:

>>> url('ssh://joe:xyz@x/repo')
<url scheme: 'ssh', user: 'joe', passwd: 'xyz', host: 'x', path: 'repo'>
>>> url('ssh://joe@x/repo')
<url scheme: 'ssh', user: 'joe', host: 'x', path: 'repo'>

Query strings and fragments:

>>> url('http://host/a?b#c')
<url scheme: 'http', host: 'host', path: 'a', query: 'b', fragment: 'c'>
>>> url('http://host/a?b#c', parsequery=False, parsefragment=False)
<url scheme: 'http', host: 'host', path: 'a?b#c'>
```

However, the `__init__` method of `class sshpeer` in `sshpeer.py` (which is used for cloning over SSH) introduces the additional restriction that passwords are not allowed in the URL:

```
    u = util.url(path, parsequery=False, parsefragment=False)
    if u.scheme != 'ssh' or not u.host or u.path is None:
        self._abort(error.RepoError(_("couldn't parse location %s") % path))

    self.user = u.user
    if u.passwd is not None:
        self._abort(error.RepoError(_("password in URL not supported")))
```

(Password in the URL is allowed for other protocols, but I'll leave finding the relevant blocks of code as an exercise for the reader, or see the documentation on [URLs](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#urls))

### Demonstrating this live -- potential help in debugging

We can use the `-v` option to see exactly how Mercurial interacts with SSH during a clone. But first, some relevant excerpts from my configuration files.

From my `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host bitbucket.ssh 
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  User hg
```

From my `.hgrc` file:

```
[ui]
# Irrelevant settings omitted
# enable compression in SSH
ssh = ssh -C
```

Now, we take a look at what happens during a clone:

```
livius@localhost ~ $ hg clone -v ssh://bitbucket.ssh/palday/splitauthor
running ssh -C bitbucket.ssh 'hg -R palday/splitauthor serve --stdio'
destination directory: splitauthor
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 3 changesets with 9 changes to 6 files
updating to branch default
resolving manifests
getting .hgignore
getting COPYING
getting README.rst
getting filter-revisions.awk
getting splitauthor.sh
getting testregex.sh
6 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

The first output line really says it all: Mercurial passes the hostname that it parses out of the URL -- in this case, your alias -- to SSH, which handles the actual issue of resolving the hostname/alias.

## Other Comments and Tips

- In your example `hg clone ssh://myAlias.ssh//path/to/repo`, you have a slash too many after the hostname, but I'm assuming this is only in the example. If not, this could be causing your path to be absolute, instead of relative to a user name (as configured in `.ssh/config`).  See also the examples in the documentation on [`hg clone`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#clone)
- I also find the exact error message a bit odd. When I try this with an undefined hostname, e.g. an alias that I haven't defined in my `.ssh/config`, I get the following error on OS X:
  `remote: ssh: Could not resolve hostname server.ssh: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`. On Linux, I get `remote: ssh: Could not resolve hostname server.ssh: Name or service not known`.

  So, my suspicion is that you're doing this on Windows. I don't know how PuTTY and the like handle the configuration file on Windows, which might mean that there's a different syntax and that's what your problem is. Running `hg clone -v` will also let you see the exact call Mercurial is making, which could also be quite useful in tracking down where things are going wrong.
- On the Unix-y systems, you can try `ssh -T  myAlias.ssh` to test the connection and your alias pass/fail, or `ssh -v  myAlias.ssh` to get exceptionally verbose output on what's happening during the connection. If `ssh -T` fails, then it's definitely an issue at a level lower than Mercurial.
- You can also set set SSH itself to be verbose: Instead of `ssh = ssh -C` like in my `.hgrc` snippet above, you can set `ssh = ssh -Cv` to get verbose debugging output from SSH. This generated about 70 lines of debugging output for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mercurial know nothing and don't use ssh-aliases
2. All usable URL-types are enumerated in `hg help urls`
3. Possible for using in Mercurial alias can (have to) be created in `[paths]` section of repository .hgrc file

Comment: Mercurial doesn't use ssh-aliases directly because it uses ssh -- SSH does the hostname resolution, not Mercurial. Mercurial first tries expanding a given "shortcut" via the `[paths]` section (which won't yet exist for a `clone` operation), then it calls the appropriate protocol handler, in this case the `ssh` libraries.